# access function alternatives without breaking encapsulation

Tags: c++, encapsulation

Is there any other way or shorter alternatives to access private base class members in a derived class other than writing a bunch of access functions or overloading operators?

Comment: you mean like using `protected` instead of `private`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, if you want true encapsulation of your base class it is recommended to make members private and only allow access via functions. This allows you to do things like preserve invariants.

But you should only provide access to members you need to. Don't just add accessors for everything without thought. If you find you do need to provide access to everything you might want to rethink your design.

If you are willing to sacrifice encapsulation you can make the members protected of course.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean from some where not within that class or a sub class then no.

But if you mean from another class you could use the protected key word instead of private then that sub class would be able to access those data members with out a getter or setter.

Answer (score 0):

Here is pretty simple example show difference

```
class parent {
  friend void f(some&);
public:
  int a_pc;
protected:
  int b_pd;
private:
  int c_pt;
};

void f(some& obj) {
  obj.a_pc = 0; // OK
  obj.b_pd = 0; // OK
  obj.c_pt = 0; // OK
}

void g(some& obj) {
  obj.a_pc = 0; // OK
  obj.b_pd = 0; // compile time error
  obj.c_pt = 0; // compile time error
}

class child : public parent {
  child() {
    a_pc = 0; // OK
    b_pd = 0; // OK
    c_pt = 0; // compile time error
  }
};
```